# Show options based on selected value in first box not like the others javascript only

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object

I am trying to fill two select option boxes with the values from an array. 
This is similar to this [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/7xp5W6ViI9a1EvskFVZz?p=preview). I am still looking to give all the options in the first box, but I need to sort the order of the second one based on the fist ones selected value.

So the first question is how do I fill the second select box with the remaining array values ?

Example: `clientRepList[0] = new ClRep("Terry","Insurance Co1","Insurance Co2");` <-- need Ins Co2 to show as well

Then the second questions is sorting the array based on the selection. 
So it is the part I can't wrap around my head.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>dashboard</title>
<script language="javascript">

    // this is the vars that we are going to sort by
    function ClRep(name, account){
        this.name = name; 
        this.account = account; 
    }

    // create the dimensional array
    clientRepList = new Array(); 
    clientRepList[0] = new ClRep("Terry","Insurance Co1","Insurance Co2");
    clientRepList[1] = new ClRep("Bob","Bank1","Bank2");

    // fill selected area with data from selected repea
    function showData(form){
        i = form.ClReps.selectedIndex; 
        var result = clientRepList[i].name;
        form.output.value = result; 
    }

    function showData2(form){
        i = form.ClReps.selectedIndex; 
        var result = clientRepList[i].account;
        form.output.value = result; 
    }       
</script>
</head>
<body onload="document.forms[0].ClReps.onchange()">

    <form>

        <!--Start script -->
        <script language="javascript">

            // Rep drop down
            var Rep = ""; 
            Rep += "<select id='rep' name='ClReps' onChange='showData(this.form)'>";

            // build popup list from array clientRepList
            for(var i = 0; i < clientRepList.length; i++){
                Rep += "<option"; 

                if(1 == 0){
                    Rep += " selected"; 
                }
                Rep += ">" + clientRepList[i].name; 
            }
            Rep += "</select><p>"
            document.write(Rep); 




            // client drop down 
            var client = ""; 
            client += "<select name='rep' onChange='showData2(this.form)'>";

            // build popup list from array clientRepList
            for(var i = 0; i < clientRepList.length; i++){
                client += "<option"; 

                if(1 == 0){
                    client += " selected"; 
                }
                client += ">" + clientRepList[i].account; 
            }
            client += "</select>"
            document.write(client); 

        </script>
    </form>
</body>
```

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/whisk/pp75pq0h/)